# How can I deal positive damage to non-undead?

Tags: spells, monsters, pathfinder-2e, damage-resistance

The [Stone-Breasted Owl](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=2464) is an incorporeal beast (and spirit), has resistance 5 to all damage, except for force, ghost touch and **positive**.

Each spell I found that deals positive damage only does so to undead:

- [Disrupt Undead](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=79) lets you *target* only undead
- [Disrupting Weapons](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=80) deals the extra positive damage only to undead
- [Holy Cascade](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=151) deals the extra positive damage only to undead

Is there some easy way to deal positive damage to a non-undead?

---

(It seems different groups developed the spells and the creatures, and they did not talk to each other)

Comment: I'm guessing, based on a couple quick checks, that this is primarily a concern for *non-Undead* [Spirits](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=149), of which there are quite a few. Anything else with weakness or resistance-beaten-by Positive should either be undead or have negative energy affinity (or similar) which causes them to respond to positive energy *as though they were* undead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You Generally Can't

Even beyond a lack of abilities/spells which could affect living creatures, under the rules for [positive energy damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=340):

> Two special types of energy damage specifically target the living and the undead. **Positive damage harms only undead creatures**, withering undead bodies and disrupting incorporeal undead. Negative damage saps life, damaging only living creatures.

The same is true with respect to dealing negative damage to an unliving creature.

It seems very likely that the stone-breasted owl was created by copying some incorporeal undead's resistances directly without considering they wouldn't be affected as living creatures. One reasonable way to preserve the likely intention is by adjusting it to work as a [gliminal's](https://2e.aonprd.com/Monsters.aspx?ID=1172) resistances:

> **Resistances** all 5 (except force, ghost touch, or **negative**; double resistance against non-magical)

Answer (score 0):

## Knights of Lastwall can do it

At least 2 spells from the Knights of Lastwall book deal positive damage without any conditions:

- [Wall of Virtue](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1127): 3rd level, creatures crossing the wall take 1d8 good and 1d8 positive damage
- [Scouring Pulse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1124): 5th level, creatures in the area take 6d8 positive damage

Comment: Even if a spell doesn't say, the fact that positive damage only harms undead is a [rule](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=340) onto itself: "Positive damage harms **only** undead creatures, withering undead bodies and disrupting incorporeal undead." Targetting a non-undead creature with scouring pulse is like targetting a non-chaotic creature with a lawful divine lance, you won't do any harm.